# Retrieving list of companies with no main addresses

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have companies stored in my database under the `company` table, and their addresses stored under `companyaddress`. A company can have many addresses.

In the `companyaddress` table, there's the usual fields such as `street1`, `postcode` etc and there's a field called `main` which is a boolean field that represents the companies main address (where I send correspondence).

I want to compile a list of companies that have addresses in `companyaddress`, but don't have any marked as `main`. So far I have this:

```
select distinct c.name from company c
left join companyaddress ca on ca.company_id = c.id
where ca.main IS FALSE
order by c.name asc
```

but it's not working correctly. It's still retrieving some companies that have an address marked as main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct c.name from company c
inner join 
(
Select Company_Id,
Sum(Case when Main=1 than 1 Else 0 End) as Totals
form companyaddress  group by Company-Id Having Sum(Case when Main=1 than 1 Else 0 End) <1
)  ca on ca.company_id = c.id
order by c.name asc
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code

```
select distinct c.name from company c
left join companyaddress ca on ca.company_id = c.id
where ca.main = 0
order by c.name asc
```

hope this will help you

Comment: This is pretty much identical to the SQL I posted in my question except you changed `IS FALSE` to `= 0`.